# How can I change a scene using python BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, scene

I was working on blender game engine, and I have no idea how to change scene using python.

I have an actuator set in to change scene, but I don't understand how

I have made a sample [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3gajcxasv1c2dt/break_demo.blend?dl=0) . What I want to do here is to switch to changed_scene using the actuator change_scene (Under player logic) using python. I need to know this, because I am making a game and the game requires switching scenes when the player dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your player dies, change a property 
(e.g. "dead" to "1")
[image: BGE property]

Then use a property sensor ("dead" == "1"?) and hook it up to scene actuator.

Okay, there's a bit more to it

I did a collision sensor, colliding with property "damage."  I added property "damage" to everything **except the floor!**

I added health to your cube player, default 100.  connected collision sensor to property actuator add "-50".

Created property sensor, health less than 1. connected to property actuator, dead = 1
[image: logic bricks]

created property sensor, dead equals 1, connected to change scene actuator. Probably could be more efficient, but it works! :)

You'll want to "and" a delay so your dramatic final collision plays out before changing scenes though

**[Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/158/)**

Comment: good answer, mind posting some pictures with it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out whether it works or not. Also isn't it possible to use a command from python to set scenes?

Comment: @BlendingJake sure :)
![damage health logic](http://ball2000.net/blender/images/GameHealthLogic.png).
![damage property set on collideables](http://ball2000.net/blender/images/DamageProp.png).

Comment: ^markdown fail lol

Answer (score 2):

Along with the answer from ball2000 , I integrated python code to delay the scene switch. The code looks something like this

```
   if player.sensors["water_collision"].positive:
        curtime = time.time()
        while(time.time() - curtime < 20):
            print(time.time() - curtime)
        player["dead_status"] = 1
```